# Difference between DateTime formats in Database and Dataset

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime-format

I have a `datetime` column in my SQL Server table which contains value like:

```
2021-01-27 00:00:00.000
```

When I fetch values from table my DataSet for this certain field is now like

```
27.1.2021. 0:00:00
```

I would like to convert this value to another format but what I get is exception

> Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Code:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(row["DO_Date"].ToString(), "DD.m.YYYY. H:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Why there is difference between value in table and then later in dataset? How to determine correct format and convert given datetime?

Comment: The first question is, what datatype are you using in your database to store these datetime values? Because if its truly a `datetime` datatype, then the value is not stored with a format, its stored as a binary value, the format is only added when displayed. And continuing with that, if you are using a `datetime` value in the database, you don't want to call `ToString()` on the database value, you want to cast it to `DateTime`. Essentially you always leave datetime values as datetime until the point you want to display it. Converting to strings prematurely is bound to cause issues.

Comment: Why do you call `ToString()` on the column value instead of just using the DateTime value?

Comment: @KlausGütter because you cannot implicitly convert object to string.

Comment: Have you tried to do `(DateTime)row["DO_Date"]` ?

Comment: @Josef but you don't want to convert it to a string at all? At least not while reading from the database, you want to convert to a DateTime.

Comment: The value in the database and the value in c# are the same.  The format that is being used to display the value is different, but the time is still the same.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError now I tried. It works! Thnx. So simple and that didn't came on my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row["DO_Date"].ToString()` returns a string which depends on your local system regional datetime setting.
Try doing the following:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(row["DO_Date"].ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

In other words - force the source format to be the same as the one you are trying to convert to.

There is a simpler way though:

```
DateTime dt = (DateTime)row["DO_Date"]
```